# HikariCP Connection pooling in multi tenant application

Tags: java, hikaricp

I'm using HikariCP in my multi-tenant application:-

```java
private Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new TenantAwareRoutingSource();

public Object insertTenants(String tenantName, String dataSource,String url, String user, String password) throws Exception {
    targetDataSources.put(tenantName, buildDataSource(dataSource,url,user,password));
    dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    return dataSource;
}

int i = 0;
private DataSource buildDataSource(String dataSource, String url, String user, String password) {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(1);
    dataSource.setPoolName("pool ->>  " + i);
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(300000);
    dataSource.setMaxLifetime(30000);
    dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
    dataSource.setDataSourceClassName(dataSource);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("url", url);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
    i++;
    return dataSource;
}
```

this above code allows to create a data source at Application run time.

For each data source I'm creating new pool name but in debug mode I'm able to see only first pool(i,e pool ->> 1)

```
2021-09-07 16:32:39.580 DEBUG 13360 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : pool ->>  1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@50c0f9ec
2021-09-07 16:32:39.580 DEBUG 13360 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : pool ->>  1 - After adding stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2
```

when I insert new tenant and When I try to access new tanant db, I'm able to access it  but I'm not able to see that pool name(i,e pool ->> 2) in the debug mood still display the pool ->> 1 in  the

How to see others pool details in the debugger.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Is creating a new pool for each tenant is good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have not the "solution", but some hints, which are hopefully help you.

To your question: I don't know your setup, but if each tenant has his own database, then it is useful to have separated connection pools.

But the way you did it, is not the best. Your `int i = 0` field feels very hacky. Here is a other approach:

```java
// it is possible, that the concurrent-hash-map will solve your problem
private Map<String, DataSource> targetDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new TenantAwareRoutingSource();

public DataSource insertTenants(String tenantName,
                                String dataSource,
                                String url, 
                                String user,
                                String password) throws Exception {

    var dataSource = buildDataSource(datasource, "pool@" + tenantName, url, user, password);
    targetDataSources.put(tenantName, dataSource);

    // I think that the problem might be here
    // All docs I found say that the tenants-map should be inserted with all tenants
    dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);


    dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    return dataSource;
}

private DataSource buildDataSource(String dataSource,
                                   String poolName,
                                   String url, 
                                   String user, 
                                   String password) {

    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(1);
    dataSource.setPoolName(poolName);
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(300000);
    dataSource.setMaxLifetime(30000);
    dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
    dataSource.setDataSourceClassName(dataSource);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("url", url);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
    
    return dataSource;
}
```

Maybe it helps, when you orientate at a example like this: https://www.bytefish.de/blog/spring_boot_multitenancy.html

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking more in functionality wise. but your suggestions will not work in my case....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create HikariConfig object with connection config details and pass that information when you create HikariDatasource.

In the HikariDataconfig section try adding the url, username and password using HikariConfig's set methods instead of addDataSourceProperty()

This worked for me and was able to create separate pools for each tenant.

```
private DataSource buildDataSource(String dataSource,
                               String poolName,
                               String url, 
                               String user, 
                               String password) {

           HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();               
           hikariConfig.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
           hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(1);
           hikariConfig.setPoolName(poolName);
           hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
           hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(300000);
           hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(30000);
           hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
           hikariConfig.setDataSourceClassName(dataSource);
           hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
           hikariConfig.setUsername(user);
           hikariConfig.setPassword(password);    
           HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
           return dataSource;
}
```